# Definition query on GDB annotation file- ArcGIS 10.3.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, attribute-table, expression, definition-query

I convert Cad annotation from Autocad, into GDB annotation using "import cad annotation" tool and this part of a big attribute table:

[image]

The "TextString" is the field i need to present on my map, but i need only the values that contain the character "k" inside them. I try to find a way to solve this issue in the definition query

[image]

I tried to select by attribute tool using this expression:
TextString ='*k', but with no success.

I know i can create a new field and start to classified every value with the character "k" inside it- but unfortunately, i have 3000 values!

also, i prefer not to use sort ascending on that field in order to gather all the wanted values and select them- there too many values.

I red [Creating definition query on layer excluding decimal values in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176646/creating-definition-query-on-layer-excluding-decimal-values-in-arcgis-for-deskto) but didn't found answer.

How can i solve this issue with the right expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i used this expression in order to get only the values with character "k":

```
TextString LIKE '%k%'
```